# JS listen for a change in db / cookies / localhost files and immediately react

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I want to logout a user edited his cookies so their new values are not match to his user info collected in database, like login token.

As same as this, I want to call http post function to server to fetch a new data as soon as new data was inserted.

I have tried **setTimeout** but after 20 minutes (approximately) the app crashed as it timed out or increased the resources requirements from a given device. I have to mention that I need to modify the changes in DOM as quick as possible, think like of a chat, we do not want to let the user wait for the fresh new message.

How Facebook for example, handles such a thing without getting timed out?
Please **try** to supply a solution **based on JS** (pure).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot provide a pure JS solution to you, but I believe you are addressing this in a wrong way.

Facebook uses react for their front-end, so they can use component lifecycle to manage updates without reloading the whole page. I would recommend you using push services or maybe websockets to communicate with your backend in a "realtime" fashion. With web sockets you can inform your frontend about when a change has been made and work from there. If you are not familiar with them https://socket.io would be a nice place to start.

This should set you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will check this out!
And pure js is not required,  third part or frameworks also accepted, I have just wanted to know if it is available via basic methods. Thanks again.

Comment: Depending on what your backend is you might also want to check Meteor. Meteor and react go along really well and allow you to make some awesome reactive "realtime" web applications but you would have to use a noSQL-like db schema.

Comment: I am using MEAN (MongoDB, Express, AngularJS, NodeJS) with AngularJS